# Tensorflow not able to invert matrix

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have a 71*71 matrix of finite float64 with an excerpt below. numpy.linalg.inv can invert that matrix but tensorflow.matrix_inverse gives this error :

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input is not
>   invertible.    [[Node: MatrixInverse_1 = MatrixInverseT=DT_FLOAT,
>   adjoint=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Moreover, I can invert it with numpy using the evalution of a tensor `np.linalg.inv(tf.matmul(XT, X).eval())` so it doesn't seem to be a data problem.

Does anyone have a solution?

```
[   -7.63790894    -5.08866978    -6.6209259    483.20855713
784.34204102   783.43835449    73.17279053    74.09223938
450.47570801   769.8269043    774.1385498    -14.69404697
-13.21867657   812.33081055   811.70593262    -3.88607216
 -5.75979233     3.88607216     5.75979233    -7.88097668    34.2455864
 36.57875061    19.74640274   710.11187744   698.85675049
669.33203125     2.1271162     17.33749199    19.96108818
902.21704102   902.27490234   902.23791504   902.22412109
902.28668213   902.18884277   902.15979004   902.18945312
902.13446045   902.12585449   902.11260986   902.16412354
902.14099121   902.1932373    902.18847656   902.07629395
-12.97049141   -22.87892342   -13.85427094   902.24389648
 -2.24357224   -12.29811287   -12.03248596    -2.06928253
-21.78663063   -18.63744736   -10.67835236   901.97436523
 33.95432281    36.67951584    19.38583755   144.95518494
156.08990479   137.80636597   902.09393311   236.29612732
902.21704102   902.15979004   902.215271     297.27478027
146.19558716    22.00869942]
```

Comment: What are these numbers you've asked us to look at? That doesn't look like at a 71 x 71 array?

Comment: Yes that not the entire thing because it is huge. It is just one row. It is only so that people don't ask to provide data. It's only a bunch of floats and numpy can process it.

Comment: Is your matrix invertible? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41841509/1140684

Comment: It's likely your matrix has an ill-conditioned leading block that can't be elimintated by `tf.matrix_inverse` (as it only uses partial pivoting) but can be eliminated by `np.linalg.inv` (as I think it uses full pivoting).  This doesn't mean `np.linlag.inv` is giving you a good inverse - in fact it's rather unlikely.  if `M = tf.matmul(XT, X).eval()`, check `np.dot(np.linalg.inv(M), M)` and see if you get something close to an identity matrix.

Comment: or just check `np.linalg.cond(M)` - if it's some ridiculously high number, you're never going to get a *useful* inverse even if `np.linalg.inv` spits something out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that your matrix is not invertible. One option is to use [Moore-Penrose matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) which is supported by NumPy as `np.linalg.pinv()`. Another option for converting your matrix into an invertible one is adding `np.eye(dims)` to your matrix. It adds error but based on the range of the numbers in your matrix, it is a good approximation.