# Confusion about inverse matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix `a`

```
matrix([[1.0e+00, 9.0e+01],
        [9.0e+01, 8.1e+03]])
```

When I ask `numpy ('1.18.1')` for the inverse of `a` I get:

```
matrix([[ 3.65365555e+12, -4.05961727e+10],
        [-4.05961727e+10,  4.51068586e+08]])
```

When I multiply them (`a*a.I`), I get:

```
matrix([[1.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 1.00048828]])
```

My understanding is that in order to calculate the inverse matrix first we need to calculate the determinant of `a` which is `1/(90*90-8100*1)`, which results in `1/0`, and division by zero is not a valid operation in `numpy`. This is the first thing that I don't understand.

The second is, I have matrix `b`:

```
matrix([[1.00e+00, 1.30e+02],
        [1.30e+02, 1.69e+04]])
```

The inverse is:

```
matrix([[ 1.80143985e+16, -1.38572296e+14],
        [-1.38572296e+14,  1.06594074e+12]])
```

When I multiply them (`b*b.I`), I get:

```
matrix([[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]])
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Here, `a` and `b` are non-invertible. [A related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841509/numpy-inverts-a-non-invertible-matrix) explains what you see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy inverts a non-invertible matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841509/numpy-inverts-a-non-invertible-matrix)

Comment: Its a non-invertible matrix. You can calculate its Rank and check.

Comment: In 1.18.2, I get `LinAlgError: Singular matrix`

Comment: @iamvegan, I guess the answers there explains it. It is still weird that some NumPy version produce a result and some produce an error.